# Question about closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Please if someone could give me an answer to this problem:

Show that $A=\{x \in l_2:|x_i| \le \frac 1 i, i=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is a closed set in $l_2$.
Where $l_2$ is the set of sequences in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|$ converges. And we write $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_i,\ldots)$ for the sequence as a whole.

I hope I've been clear enough, Thanks.

Comment: Is it the intersection of a collection of closed sets perhaps?

Comment: hmm good idea, ill try that :)

Comment: Maybe use the fact that $f_n(x) = x_n$ is continuous?

Comment: @DavidMitra $A \subset l_2$ and not in the closed interval you mentioned.

Comment: Consider the sets $A_n = f_n^{-1} ([-{1 \over n}, {1 \over n}])$, where $f_n(x) = x_n$.

Comment: Just a comment on notation: $l_2$ usually denotes square summable sequences, is this a typo or are you using somewhat non-standard notation on purpose?

Comment: I assume that you mean $\sum_i |x_i|^2 $ converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by $l_2$ you mean the usual square summable sequences.

Suppose $x \notin A$. Then $|x_k| > {1 \over k}$ for some $k$.

Then
$B(x,{1 \over 2}(|x_k|-{1 \over k})) \subset A^c$.

To see this, suppose $y \in B(x,{1 \over 2}(|x_k|-{1 \over k})) $.
Note that $|y_k-x_k| \le \sqrt{\sum_n |y_n-x_n|^2} = \|y-x\| < {1 \over 2}(|x_k|-{1 \over k})$.
Then
$|y_k| \ge |x_k|-|y_k-x_k| \ge {1 \over k} + (|x_k|-{1 \over k}) - {1 \over 2}(|x_k|-{1 \over k}) = {1 \over k} + {1 \over 2} (|x_k|-{1 \over k}) > {1 \over k}$, and so $y \notin A$.

Comment: yes but, $\frac 1 {2k} \le \frac 1 k$ so  that it doesn't follow in the last step that $|y_k| \ge \frac 1 k$?

Comment: Fixed it. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: why do you have this on the last line ${1 \over k} + (|x_k|-{1 \over k})$? where does the plus part after $1 \over k$ come from?

Comment: $|x_k| = {1 \over k} + |x_k|-{1 \over k}$.

Comment: all right I see now

Comment: that's a great choice for $\varepsilon$ that you have there, how did you come up with that :).

Answer (score 1):

Your set is but $\cap_{i\in\mathbf{N}^{*}} p_i^{-1} ([-1/i,1/i]) $ where $p_i : (x_i)_i \mapsto x_i$ are the projections. These projections are continuous, so that your set is an intersection of closed sets, and is therefore closed.